# How to connect mssql data base(ssl is enabled.) through JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have one database that is SSL enabled. and other database is SSL is not enabled.

I have requirement to connect the SSL enabled database through jdbc url then it should throw SSL exception.
If I have to connect database with proper jdbc url then it should not throw SSL exception.

Why this requirement is I don't know connected databse is ssl is enabled or not.

I have tried `jdbc:sqlserver://10.29.34.222:1433;databaseName=test`, this jdbc url is working for both SSL enabled database and SSL not enabled database.
So this one does not help for my requirement.

Can any one please help me on this.

Comment: Add `;encrypt=true` to the connection string?

Comment: If I have add ;encrypt=true to the connection string It will connect both ssl enabled and ssl nt enabled database.?

Comment: Can you please help me on this. I am really stuck on this requirement

Comment: It will only connect to those DBs if it can ensure an encrypted connection. If it connects, it's encrypted. Maybe I'm misunderstanding?